# Hash sign (#) in C console application with command line arguments

Tags: php, c, special-characters, command-line-arguments

I am trying to send a color code from a php-website to a port. For that I use a console application on the server. It looks like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        _tprintf ( _T("Command: %s\n"), argv[3]);

        if ( !Messenger::GetInstance()->SetServer( argv[1], _tstoi(argv[2]), false) )
        {
            _tprintf( _T("ERROR: SetServer( 192.168.10.50, 30000, false) failed") );
        }
        else
        {
            _TCHAR *p = wcstok(argv[3], _T(";"));
            while (p)
            {
                Messenger::GetInstance()->SendCommand( p );

                //_tprintf ( _T("Token: %s\n"), p);
                p = wcstok(NULL, _T(";"));
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The exe is called like this:

```
$command = "Command=LIGHT-COLOR #00ff00";
$returnMsg = exec("PassAlong.exe \"" . $server . "\" \"" . $port . "\" \"" . $command . "\"");
```

Unfortunately, the console app only returns this:
Command: LIGHT-COLOR

It seems that the string is cut off at the hash sign #.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thank you for your help! It is much appreciated!
Christian

Comment: Does this happen from the console as well as through PHP?

Comment: sending the command directly from the console app itself works fine with the #. THank you for your comment, it works now, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the #, like so:

```
$command = "Command=LIGHT-COLOR \\#00ff00";
```

The first '\' is to escape the '\' that escapes the '#' if that makes sense.  I am not a PHP programmer, so this isn't tested.

Comment: It works now. You were right, I have to escape it, but using slashes did not work. 
Instead I had to use %23.

Thanks :)